# react-router-domのuseLocation()でprotocolとhostを取得する方法

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

react-router-domのuseLocation()でprotocolとhostを取得する方法はありますか？
useLocation()ではなく、window.location.protocol、window.location.hostとするしかないのでしょうか？

```js
import { memo, VFC, useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

export const Test: VFC = memo(() => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(location.pathname); // OK
    console.log(location.protocol); // NG
    console.log(location.host); // NG
    console.log(window.location.protocol); // OK
    console.log(window.location.host); // OK
  }, [location]);

  return <></>;
});
```

各ライブラリのバージョンは以下を使用しています。

```
react-router-dom@5.3.0
react@17.0.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Collaborator`によると、[React Routerはそうした機能をサポートしていない](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/7638#issuecomment-701034488)ようです。

`useLocation`という名前がややミスリードなのですが、
ここでいう`Location`は[Locationオブジェクト(つまりドキュメントの位置を表すURL)](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Location)ではなく、
React RouterがSPAで擬似的なルーティングを行うにあたっての内部的なロケーション情報、という意味合いのようです。

> useLocation()ではなく、window.location.protocol、window.location.hostとするしかないのでしょうか？

はい。その方法になると思います。